# Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, autofilter

Right now I am doing coding to set a filter for a data chart. Basically, I don't know how to post the data sheet up here so just try to type them ):

(starting from the left is column A)
Name        *  BDevice   *  Quantity * Sale*  Owner

Basically I need to filter out for 2 column:
-The BDevice with any word contain "M1454" or "M1467" or "M1879" (It means that M1454A or M1467TR would still fit in)
-The Owner with PROD or RISK

Here is the code I wrote:

```
Sub AutoFilter()

  ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet..Range(B:B).Select

  Selection.Autofilter Field:=1 Criteria1:=Array( _
      "*M1454*", "*M1467*", "*M1879*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=4 Criteria1:="=PROD" _
      , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=RISK"

End Sub
```

When I run the code, the machine returns error 1004 and the part which seems to be wrong is the Filter part 2 ( I  am not sure about the use of Field, so I can not say it for sure)

**Edit; Santosh:** When I try your code, the machine gets error 9 subscript out of range. The error came from the with statement. (since the data table has A to AS column so I just change to A:AS)

Comment: Can you let me know the Sheet name on which your data resides?

Comment: AutoFilter is a built-in VBA term.  This causes a compile error on my machine when I execute the code from @Santosh within the sheet object.  Renaming the Sub resolves this issue.

Answer (score 8):

While there is a maximum of two direct wildcards per field in the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx), pattern matching can be used to create an array that replaces the wildcards with the **Operator:=xlFilterValues** option. A [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) helps the wildcard matching.

The second field is a simple Criteria1 and Criteria2 direct match with a **Operator:=xlOr** joining the two criteria.

```
Sub multiWildcardFilter()
    Dim a As Long, aARRs As Variant, dVALs As Object

    Set dVALs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dVALs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'build a dictionary so the keys can be used as the array filter
            aARRs = .Columns(2).Cells.Value2
            For a = LBound(aARRs, 1) + 1 To UBound(aARRs, 1)
                Select Case True
                    Case aARRs(a, 1) Like "MK1454*"
                        dVALs.Add Key:=aARRs(a, 1), Item:=aARRs(a, 1)
                    Case aARRs(a, 1) Like "MK1467*"
                        dVALs.Add Key:=aARRs(a, 1), Item:=aARRs(a, 1)
                    Case aARRs(a, 1) Like "MK1879*"
                        dVALs.Add Key:=aARRs(a, 1), Item:=aARRs(a, 1)
                    Case Else
                        'no match. do nothing
                End Select
            Next a

            'filter on column B if dictionary keys exist
            If CBool(dVALs.Count) Then _
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=dVALs.keys, _
                                      Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=False
            'filter on column E
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="PROD", Operator:=xlOr, _
                                  Criteria2:="RISK", VisibleDropDown:=False

            'data is filtered on MK1454*, MK1467* or MK1879* (column B)
            'column E is either PROD or RISK
            'Perform work on filtered data here
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    dVALs.RemoveAll: Set dVALs = Nothing
End Sub
```

If exclusions¹ are to be added to the filtering, their logic should be placed at the top of the Select.. End Select statement in order that they are not added through a false positive to other matching criteria.

[image: multi_Wildcard_Filter_Before]
                        <sup>Before applying AutoFilter Method</sup>

[image: multi_Wildcard_Filter_After]
                        <sup>After applying AutoFilter w/ multiple wildcards</sup>

---

¹ <sub>See [Can Advanced Filter criteria be in the VBA rather than a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532282/can-advanced-filter-criteria-be-in-the-vba-rather-than-a-range) and [Can AutoFilter take both inclusive and non-inclusive wildcards from Dictionary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614417/can-autofilter-take-both-inclusive-and-non-inclusive-wildcards-from-dictionary-k) for more on adding exclusions to the dictionary's filter set.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

For using partial strings to exclude rows and include blanks you should use

```
'From Jeeped's code
Dim dVals As Scripting.Dictionary
Set dVals = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dVals.CompareMode = vbTextCompare    


Dim col3() As Variant
Dim col3init As Integer

'Swallow row3 into an array; start from 1 so it corresponds to row
For col3init = 1 to Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.count
    col3(col3init) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(col3init,3),Cells(col3init,3)).Value
Next col3init

Dim excludeArray() As Variant
'Partial strings in below array will be checked against rows
excludeArray = Array("MK1", "MK2", "MK3")

Dim col3check As Integer
Dim excludecheck as Integer
Dim violations As Integer
For col3check = 1 to UBound(col3)
    For excludecheck = 0 to UBound(excludeArray) 
         If Instr(1,col3(col3check),excludeArray(excludecheck)) <> 0 Then
             violations = violations + 1
             'Sometimes the partial string you're filtering out for may appear more than once.
         End If
    Next col3check

    If violations = 0 and Not dVals.Exists(col3(col3check)) Then
         dVals.Add Key:=col3(col3check), Item:=col3(col3check) 'adds keys for items where the partial strings in excludeArray do NOT appear
    ElseIf col3(col3check) = "" Then
         dVals.Item(Chr(61)) = Chr(61) 'blanks
    End If
    violations = 0
Next col3check
```

The dVals.Item(Chr(61)) = Chr(61) idea came from Jeeped's other answer here
[Multiple Filter Criteria for blanks and numbers using wildcard on same field just doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364635/multiple-filter-criteria-for-blanks-and-numbers-using-wildcard-on-same-field-jus)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

max 2 wildcard expression for Criteria1 works. Refer this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/799b2f75-c1e3-47c9-891a-b92325cb493f)

```
Sub AutoFilter()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:E")
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("*M1454*", "*M1467*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=PROD", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=RISK"
    End With

End Sub
```