# Auto filter with multiple wildcards

Tags: excel, autofilter

Is there a way to use an Excel auto filter, whereby you set a predefined list of values to filter by, and it will return all the cells in a column that contain that phrase? For example imagine the data below (all in a single column).

```
       A
1    NAMES
2  Brian
3  Brian, John
4  Brian, Mark
5  Mark, John
```

The filter would have three predefined values, `Brian`, `John` and `Mark`, when you select either 1 or more options, it satisfies all selected filters? So in this example `Brian` would return the first three cells, where as selecting `Mark` and `John` would return only the last.

I know this is possible to do once in a list of data using the `Advanced Filter`, but I'm looking for a real-time way of doing this many times.

Comment: Do you want the filtering to be performed "in place" or do you want the results displayed in a separate list ??

Comment: In place, i have explored showing it in a different place but unfortunately that will not work for my specific application, so has to remain in place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot filter more than two criteria with wildcards. The nature of your sample data is such that you would be using ="Brian*", ="Mark*" or ="*John" to wildcard the first names as either *Begins with...* or  *Ends with...* criteria. You can only use two of these in any one filter operation. You cannot add a third by creating an array of wildcarded values.

This works:

```
with activesheet.cells(1, 1).currentregion
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Brian*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*John"
end with
```

This does not work:

```
with activesheet.cells(1, 1).currentregion
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Brian*", "Mark*", "*John"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
end with
```

Comment: See [Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards/34822944#34822944) and [Can AutoFilter take both inclusive and non-inclusive wildcards from Dictionary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards/34822944#34822944) for methods on getting around the two wildcard limit.

Answer (score -1):

The second method doesn't work because if you are using wildcards in an array to autofilter you are limited to only 2 terms. There are workarounds and solutions on the web.

Comment: Please include links to some of the workarounds and solutions on the web.