# VBA: Filtering by multiple criteria (more than 2) using wildcards

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am looking to create a filter rule in VBA with wildcards ("**contains**") regardless of location of the text.

For example, I want to filter anything that contains the string `mwv` or `westrock` or `meadw`or `jacob`, etc..

I've tried this a couple of ways without success.
First:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "*Meadw*", "*WestRock*", "*mvw*", "*Jacob*"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

And

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
Criteria1:="=*westrock*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*mwv*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=*meadw*"
```

For the latter, I'm limited to 2 criteria. The former doesn't seem to work at all.

I suppose a workaround would be replicating my data on a separate sheet(s), filtering 2 at a time on each sheet, and merging them after all is said and done, but that hardly seems efficient.

Is there a more efficient manner of accomplishing this? A pascal programmer thought that `Regex` may be useful in this circumstance, but unfortunately I don't have any experience using that.

Comment: [See This](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/619351-filter-multiple-criteria-visual-basic-applications.html) it may help

Comment: Thanks @RohanK, but unfortunately doesn't solve the wildcard issue. You can filter multiple criteria in an array, yes, but using a wildcard in an array doesn't work because it's looking for an exact string.

Comment: You can not do a filter on more than two with wildcards at a time.  so do multiple filters, one right after the other.

Comment: @ScottCraner How can I do that on the same sheet without the second filter overriding the first?

Comment: To be honest I have never done it I have only read it somewhere and now can't find it, but I thought you would literally just put two auto filter lines back to back with he different criteria and it would work.  I do know for a certain that you cannot put more than two wildcard criteria in one autofilter.  See [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820896/auto-filter-with-multiple-wildcards)

Comment: See [THIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/799b2f75-c1e3-47c9-891a-b92325cb493f/autofilter-more-than-2-criteria-on-strings-with-wildcard?forum=isvvba) for another type of work around.

Comment: @ScottCraner The helper column is a very interesting workaround, thanks.