# Excel VBA - Array limitations

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Here's a string of code I'm writing:

```
test.Range("$A:$D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("CA8*", "AU8*")
```

In my data set this line returns 227 rows. However when I add another criteria in my array, it stops working and will not show any filtered rows. Adding a third criteria in the array is supposed to make this action return a total of 895 rows. However I don't see any filtered rows if I have all 3 criteria in my array. I have to manually filter to validate the 895 rows. It looks like it only works when I have 2 criteria, which makes me wonder - perhaps due to the size of my data set, is there a memory restriction to what I can define the array as?

There are many criteria I would like to define in my array if possible. If there's an alternative way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto filter with multiple wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820896/auto-filter-with-multiple-wildcards) • You cannot filter for more than 2 wildcards (using `*`).

Comment: Thank you - I will look at that thread :)