# Filtering Columns that "*Contain*" 2 or More Variables

Tags: excel, vba, filter

So here is what I am trying to do. I have a table similar to this:

```
ID | Fruit  | Code                    | 
 ______________________________________
2  | Orange | DU + AZ + BL + FD      
3  | Grape  | CD + AG + BH           
4  | Kiwi   | AA + BA + CA           
5  | Lime   | DZ + CA + AA + DU + BL
```

I am currently filtering the table like this. (This looks for a change in the E3 field and automaticaly updates/filters if I make a change.)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
 If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
  Range("A2").AutoFilter
 Else
  Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array(Range("G3").Value, Range("H3").Value, Range("I3").Value)
 End If

End If

End Sub


In G3 I have "*AA*"
In H3 I have "*BA*"
In I3 I have "*CA*"
```

This would filter down to any rows with any of those (G3:I3) in the code column

As long as I have a value in all 3 fields it works fine. My question is how can I still filter like this if I only have one or two codes and blanks in the others.

Edit: I have also tried this. Just filters to nothing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, arr As Variant
arr = Array(Range("G3:I3"))


If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
 If Range("E3").Value = "" Then
  Range("C2").AutoFilter
 Else

With Sheet1

    'to filter each value in the array one at a time
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        .Range("C2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr(i)
    Next i

End With


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a variable instead of hard coding it?

Comment: `Array("*AA*")` would also work, so I'm not sure I'm following the issue, as you need only to remove the other criterion.

Comment: I meant to use cell values. I have code that splits a cell into 6 columns. Using a delimter. 
   =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($J3,";",REPT(" ",LEN($J3))),(K1-1)*LEN($J3)+1,LEN($J3)))

Comment: For >2 values with wildcards I think you need to use Advanced Filter.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820896/auto-filter-with-multiple-wildcards

Comment: See [Using string array as criteria in VBA autofilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404176/using-string-array-as-criteria-in-vba-autofilter).  This explains how one can create a loop for the criteria, which should work for your use of cell values.

Comment: @Cyril I think I am doing something wrong. Can you help me with my edit?