# Ignoring empty cells in Criteria range while using AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to filter particular words from a range in a sheet. For this purpose, I'm using the *AutoFilter* option. However, when I'm executing the VBA code, it clearly isn't working because when I have empty cells in the range from the *Filters Sheet*, the **"="** takes the empty cells into account and all the data gets filtered out as a result, unless all the cells in the range from the *Filters Sheet* are occupied. Is there a way to ignore empty cells in the range **Range("B6:F6")** in the criteria to avoid this issue?

Here's what I want to implement:

```
rngData.AutoFilter Field:=a, Criteria1:="=" & "*" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Filters").Range("B6:F6").Value & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Remove `, Operator:=xlFilterValues` and see if it works. This is used if you have an array as `Criteria1` but then wildcards `*` are not allowed and it litterally filters for `*` as a non-wildcard, which obviously does not exist in your data. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29820896/auto-filter-with-multiple-wildcards • If that does not work please show a [mcve] of your issue including some short example data to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I removed **Operator:=xlFilterValues** but it didn't work.  I have illustrated my issue below for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example to illustrate my issue:

**Data:**

[image]

The idea is to give the user the option to filter the car manufacturer of choice. For this reason, I created a seperate sheet called *Filter* so that the user can input the filter. For eg:

[image]

If the user enters BMW in range ***Range("B6:F6")***, only row Nr. 2 from the data remains and the other 2 rows get filtered out. I have chosen range ***Range("B6:F6")*** so that I can give the user the option of filtering multiple car manufacturers if needed.

The problem is that if the cells C6, D6, E6 and F6 are empty, the *AutoFilter* option in VBA doesn't execute accurately due to the manner in which I wrote my code as described above. Therefore, is there a way where I can ignore the empty cells in my range if the user doesn't input a car manufacturer so that *AutoFilter* filters out the data accurately?