Use Autofilter VBA in Excel for more than 2 criteria
I am trying to filter a data set looking for a scalable set of criteria. Initially with just two criteria it was working fine. Example of the first run:
    Range("A1:M1").Select
     Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Product A*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Product B*"

This would produce a sheet that contained rows with either a or b. However I needed to add a third criteria, and will need to have five additional options in the future. So I changed it to the following:
Range("A1:M1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("*Product A*", "*Product B*", "*Product C*"), Operator:=xlOr

This only shows options that have the final "Product C" included in the row. I cannot figure out why this is the case, I would appreciate any help greatly. I need it to display any row with any of the three options.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837083/478884   When filtering using wildcards you can only supply a maximum of two values.  There are workarounds posted at that link.

Filter Data With More Than 2 Wildcard Criteria
Before

After

Main (Usage Example)
Sub MultiWildcardFilterListTEST()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 6
    Dim CRITERIA_PATTERNS() As Variant: CRITERIA_PATTERNS = Array( _
        "*Product A*", "*Product B*", "*Product C*") ' add more

    ' Reference the main objects: worksheet ('ws') and range ('rg').
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off auto-filtering
    
    ' Assuming the list starts in 'A1'.
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
     
    ' Filter.
    
    MultiWildcardFilterList rg, CRITERIA_COLUMN, CRITERIA_PATTERNS

End Sub

The Helper Method
Sub MultiWildcardFilterList( _
        rg As Range, _
        CriteriaColumn As Long, _
        CriteriaPatterns As Variant)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Multi-Wildcard Filter List"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Validate the number of rows ('rCount') and columns ('rg.Columns.Count').
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    If rCount < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Not enough rows (2) in range """ _
            & rg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If rg.Columns.Count < CriteriaColumn Then
        MsgBox "Not enough columns (" & CriteriaColumn & ") in range """ _
            & rg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Return the values of the criteria column ('rg.Columns(CriteriaColumn)')
    ' in a 2D one-based array ('Data').
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Columns(CriteriaColumn).Value
    ' since we ensured that there are at least 2 rows ('If rCount < 2 Then')
    
    ' Convert the patterns ('CriteriaPatterns()') to lowercase
    ' ('LowerCasePatterns()') since we're about to convert all values
    ' of the criteria column to lowercase and use the 'Like' operator
    ' where the comparison is case-sensitive.
    
    Dim pDiff As Long: pDiff = LBound(CriteriaPatterns) - 1
    Dim pCount As Long: pCount = UBound(CriteriaPatterns) - pDiff
    Dim LowerCasePatterns() As String: ReDim LowerCasePatterns(1 To pCount)
        
    Dim p As Long
    
    For p = 1 To pCount
        LowerCasePatterns(p) = LCase(CriteriaPatterns(p + pDiff))
    Next p
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the array ('Data') and return the matches
    ' in the keys ('dict.Keys') of a dictionary ('dict').
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    'dict.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare ' default since 'LCase' (it's faster)
    
    Dim r As Long, rStr As String
    
    For r = 2 To rCount ' skip header
        rStr = LCase(CStr(Data(r, 1)))
        For p = 1 To pCount
            If rStr Like LowerCasePatterns(p) Then dict(rStr) = Empty: Exit For
        Next p
    Next r
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No criteria found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Filter the range.
    
    rg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, dict.keys, xlFilterValues

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

