# Using Autofilter to filter blanks and numeric values

Tags: excel, vba

enter code hereI am completely new to vba and I am preparing a macro for automating daily activity reports. Part of the report is filtering the data based on certain values and copying it in another workbook.
I'm stuck here and need your help.
column x has "Names of customers", but there might be Blank fields, Dates and ID numbers.

I figured out filtering blank fields but not able to find how to filter dates & ID numbers or in general numerics.

this is the code I'm using:

```
range("A1").AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=Array(""), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

dates can be 5/28/2016
id numbers can be 292051102901

I have searched for similar posts but could not find it.

Please let me know if additional code needs to be shared or a sample file to work.
[Snippet of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0mCF.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro while changing/setting the filter? The resulting code might tell you how to do it manually. It's a trick that works sometimes, not always.

Comment: Perhaps the Answer by @Jeeped in the post [Multiple Filter Criteria for blanks and numbers using wildcard on same field just doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30364635/multiple-filter-criteria-for-blanks-and-numbers-using-wildcard-on-same-field-jus) may help you in working out the solution.

Comment: @pintxo yes i tried macro recording but it captured the specific values from the cells. I require the format of those values since these values will change.

Comment: @skkakkar i went through jeeped's post, honestly i didnt understand anything :( im sorry. As far as i understood from that post, the first 3 digits are constant and a dictionary is built to capture it. In my case, the values are random dates and serial numbers, so im thinking if there is a format or a logic to any value with numbers in it, will do for me, i guess so.

Comment: @Deepak S If you can upload snapshot of sample data ( If it is confidential you can put fictitious figures but retaining its true representation), I would be in a better position to help you with suitable working on your data and also explaining     Jeeped's post. It's mid-night here. If you do something as suggested , I may be able to look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @skkakkar sorry for the delayed response, I had a very lazy weekend due to heat :) I uploaded the snapshot but not sure if its showing for you. please let me know. so, in the CONTRACT NAME column, blank fields are filtered with my code. No idea on how to filter other values with numbers.

Comment: @Deepak S I too was suffering from Heat stroke, Now I have sufficiently recovered. In case you have not resolved your problem in the mean time , I can try to workout a solution for your problem.

Comment: @skkakkar Oh, please be careful with the heat. No, I have not resolved the problem yet :( And, i'm currently exploring another function "excluding list in auto filter, instead selection list"

Comment: @Deepak S Please look into this post of mine [While extracting dates and numerics from mixed strings not able to remove zero from results.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806072/while-extracting-dates-and-numerics-from-mixed-strings-not-able-to-remove-zero-f) This should be able to resolve your problem. In case of any difficulty, please let me know.

Comment: @skkakkar that worked almost. It requires little modification to get the appropriate result. Actually, I found a work around using conditional formatting.

Comment: @Deepak S I am glad that you could work it out. You can post it as an answer from your own side, since there are no other responses. You can accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Comment: @skkakkar thank you for helping me out. have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work Around:
This helped me to avoid inserting another column and filter it by target values Two criteria.
1. cells that contain 'Blanks' will be formatted to a specific color
2. cells that contain value between '0' & '999999999999' will be formatted to same color of 1st criteria, then, filter it by color.
Used macro recorder and got the code :-

```
Columns("U:U").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _ Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=999999999999"

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
.Bold = True 
.Italic = False 
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6 
.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262 
End With 
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False 
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= "=LEN(TRIM(U1))=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority 
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font 
.Bold = True 
.Italic = False 
.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6 
.TintAndShade = -0.499984740745262 
End With 
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False 
range("U4").Select 
Selection.AutoFilter range("A1").AutoFilter field:=21, Criteria1:=RGB(151, 71, 6), operator:=xlFilterFontColor
```