# While extracting dates and numerics from mixed strings not able to remove zero from results.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am extracting numerics and dates from a column containing mixed strings as shown in the sample table below.

```
Subscriber Name  
123456789123 null null  
null  
null null null  
5/23/2016  
hello   
Good Evening  
null 6/11/2016
```

I am using the Array formula entering with CSE:

```
{=IFERROR(--SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&Q2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(Q2,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10),"")}
```

I am getting following results showing 0 in cells with empty or text cells whereas I require it to be empty. I have tried by inserting IFERROR and "--" also but I still get 0 in the cells. What correction is required in the formula. Further I am also open to VBA solution, if someone offers.

[image: results from formula][image: desired results]

Comment: the date is obviously a string since it mixed up in a cell with a string.  The question I have is it always the same format with no leading zero for the month?  is there a leading zero for the day?

Comment: wrap the whole thing up in IF(BIG_HONKING_FORMULA=0,"",BIG_HONKING_FOMULA)?  you should not need the -- in front of sumproduct, as sumproduct can only be a number.  You also do not need the -- in front of MID since you are sending it through math calc by multiplying it by the row( )

Comment: When no number is found your formula without the iferror is evaluating to 0 which is why you iferror is not catching anything.  You could invert your results twice to cause an error when the results are zero.  You know 1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA will give you a DIV/0! error for cells you want blank.  You also know this will screw up the results for the rows you do want!  so you could do 1/(1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA) which should generate an error when your formula is zero and should leave your results untouched for what you want to keep.

Comment: finally IF you are using sumproduct to generate array like operations, but are not actually using the summing feature of sum product, take a look at the aggregate function.  It has the ability to ignore errors and operations 14 and 15 will cause array like operations to occur like sumproduct does.

Comment: @Forward Ed  When we enter date as 06/21/2016 Excel converts it to 6/21/2016, hence I have not used leading zeros. Second your suggested correction is not giving desired results. Please see the [uploaded snapshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65565270/stackoverflow/Jun_2016/results%20post%20correction.png)

Comment: @Forward Ed I am giving a try to your 1/(1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA) suggestion.

Comment: you changed IFERROR to IF,  when you change it to if, it does not evaluated the same way.  Notice in my example, I had BIG_HONKING_FORMULA twice?  the first time is for a logical check to see if it equals 0.  If that is true then return "".  If it is false then perform the BIG_HONKING_FORMULA.

Comment: BIG_HONKING_FORMULA should be equal to `SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&Q2,LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(Q2,ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10)` roughly...I may have miscounted bracket.  basically everything that is the sumproduct.

Comment: @Forward Ed your 1/(1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA) suggestion works fine. Thank you. Please put it as answer, so that I may accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no number is found your formula without the iferror is evaluating to 0 which is why you iferror is not catching anything. You could invert your results twice to cause an error when the results are zero. You know:

```
=1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA
```

will give you a DIV/0! error for cells you want blank. You also know this will screw up the results for the rows you do want! so you could do:

```
=1/(1/BIG_HONKING_FORMULA)
```

which should generate an error when your formula is zero and should leave your results untouched for what you want to keep.