# Can Advanced Filter criteria be in the VBA rather than a range?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, autofilter

After trying in vain to set more than 2 criteria in a normal AutoFilter fashion via VBA, I have come to learn that it must be done via advanced filter.

offending example:

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=ColNum, Criteria1:="A*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="B*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="C*"
```

I am hoping to pass the criteria through to a function (rather than a macro) from a PowerShell script. I have it all working fine and as expected for 1 criteria, but now I'd like 3.

I suppose I could instead write a macro to insert a new sheet, write in the criteria then filter on that new range but I'd rather check the preferred way first.

Comment: Can't be anything but a range I'm afraid.

Comment: Create a variant array of wildcard matches and then use the array of full values with the standard [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx). I've done this with a dictionary object to use its unique index property.

Comment: Won't this become a custom filter and fail due to >2?

Comment: @Chris - see my generic solution below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To filter on multiple wildcards, create a variant array of wildcard matches and then use the array of full values with the standard AutoFilter method. You can minimize the array by putting a dictionary object to use with its unique index property.

Consider the following sample data.

[image: autofilter_multi_wilcard]

Run this code.

```
Sub multiWildcards()
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant, dVALs As Object
    Dim colNum As Long

    Set dVALs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dVALs.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    colNum = 2 'column B

    With Worksheets(1)
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            vVALs = .Columns(colNum).Cells.Value2
            For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
                If Not dVALs.exists(vVALs(v, 1)) Then
                    Select Case UCase(Left(vVALs(v, 1), 1))
                        Case "A", "B", "C"
                            dVALs.Add Key:=vVALs(v, 1), Item:=vVALs(v, 1)
                        Case Else
                            'do nothing
                    End Select
                End If
            Next v

            If CBool(dVALs.Count) Then
                'populated the dictionary; now use the keys
                .AutoFilter Field:=colNum, Criteria1:=dVALs.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            Else
                Debug.Print "Nothing to filter on; dictionary is empty"
            End If

            '.CurrentRegion is now filtered on A*, B*, C* in column B
            'do something with it
        End With
    End With

    dVALs.RemoveAll: Set dVALs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Results should be:

[image: autofilter_multi_wilcard_results]

These results can be duplicated with many other wildcard scenarios. The [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) is ideal as it supports the **Like** keyword for building your collection of matches. By starting with a value dump into a regular variant array, cycling through even large rows of data can be done quickly.

Comment: Interesting, will give it a go. Thanks very much. Next step is passing the array of values to VBA from PowerShell!

Comment: Just tried to run this and get type mismatch on .AutoFilter Field:=colNum, Criteria1:=dVALs.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: This may have something to do with your version of Excel and its SP. Try `Criteria1:=(dVALs.keys)`. I honestly did not make the image up.

Comment: I wouldn't dare suggest you did! It's likely me making some mistake. I've added the brackets but get the same error. I'm using Excel 2013 if it helps

Comment: Could you try [this sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/AutoFilter_Multi_Wildcards_Sample.xlsb)? It is a small XLSB.

Comment: If the dictionary is empty, you will receive that error. See my error control addition above.

Comment: Apologies for the slow reply, thank you very much for the further help. Will give it a test this morning.

Comment: I now get no error but nothing happens, I've tried updating the cases to my actual values to be filtered on, including and not including wildcard. I remember you mentioning the Like keyword but don't see it used anywhere, is this intended? I'm unable to use your test spreadsheet as dropbox is not available on this network. I run all my macros from a personal XLSB, is this sufficient? The autofilter is removed so I know the macro is being run.

Comment: I can confirm the issue now is the dictionary is empty, wasn't sure where to see the debug output so I added a MsgBox and it appears.

Comment: Ignore the above - got it working. Absolutely a case of user not being clear of requirements! Once I properly went through your code I realized it was selecting on 1 letter of the value (from the A,B,C example). My actual scenario needs to filter on the first 3, so I updated the "Select Case" line and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: Glad you got that working. It's a powerful tool in just a handful of code lines.

Comment: Absolutely, I've put in a "sub" select to try on lengths of 2 as well which works! I want to extend it now to take an array of values, but I'll give that a go and create a separate question in the future if I get stuck. Thanks again

Comment: btw, `Debug.Print` reports to the VBE's **Immediate** window. Tap Ctrl+G to reveal it (alternately View ► Immediate Window).

Comment: is there a way to specifically exclude a wildcard? For example I want to include "A*" and "B*", but exclude "BB*"?

Comment: After meeting the B requirement, you could easily add a line like `If Not Left(vVALs(v, 1), 2) = "BB" Then dVALs.Add Key:=...`. If there were many of these, it might make sense to assign `vVALs(v, 1)` to a string variable just above the `Select Case` ands use the string var in all subsequent conditions.

Comment: Hmm ok, I need to make it a bit more flexible. This has so many comments now and I've altered the macro so it might be better to make a new question.

Comment: Drop one more note here when you do and I'll try to have a look.

Comment: New question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614417/can-autofilter-take-both-inclusive-and-non-inclusive-wildcards-from-dictionary-k