# Autofilter and display rows based on the xlOR criterions from 2 columns?

Tags: arrays, excel, conditional-formatting, autofilter, vba

I am looking to display rows where Column L = "ABC" as well as display rows where Column AA <> "DEF". I tried,

```
Cells.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=xlOr, 
                 Field:=28, Criteria1:="<>DEF"
```

, but seems this only displays rows where its L column is "ABC". However, I want to show the union of rows where either its column L is "ABC", or its column AA is not "DEF". Where have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and studying the generated code?

Comment: The [Range.AutoFit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820840.aspx) does not work that way. Use the [Advanced Filter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221800(v=office.11).aspx) or (if you have a column of unique values) a dictionary of 'keys'.

Comment: btw, wouldn't column AA be `Field:=27` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sup>**TL;DR:** For the quickest method to implement and understand, scroll down to the second option with the 'helper' column.</sup>
>   <sub>Come back to explore the other methods when you have time to match new techniques to your particular situation
>  and maximize efficiency.</sub>

As mentioned in comments, the **xlOr** operator in the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) does not work across multiple fields; only for a single field. As I see it, you have at least five options.

---

**Option 1: [Advanced Filter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221800.aspx)**

Set up an area for the [Advanced Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221800.aspx) criteria. In the following, I've used AC1:AD3. Advanced Filter OR criteria goes on successive rows.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Advanced_Filter]
           <sup>Sample data with [Advanced Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221800.aspx) criteria area</sup>

As code:

```
    Dim crit As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("AC1:AD1") = Array(.Range("L1").Value, .Range("AA1").Value)
        .Range("AC2") = "ABC"
        .Range("AD3") = "<>DEF"
        Set crit = .Range("AC1:AD3")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
                            CriteriaRange:=crit, Unique:=False
        End With
    End With
```

---

**Option 2: [.AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) on 'helper' column with worksheet formula**

A 'helper' column is an easy method to make multiple determinations. Put a simple formula that resolves to TRUE/FALSE based on your multiple criteria (e.g. `=OR($L2="ABC",$AA2<>"DEF")`) into an unused column and .AutoFilter on that column.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Helper_Column]
           <sup>Sample data showing worksheet formula in 'Helper' column</sup>

As code:

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, .Columns.Count)
                .Formula = "=OR($L2=""ABC"",$AA2<>""DEF"")"
            End With
        End With
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=.Columns.Count, Criteria1:="TRUE"
            'clean up the 'helper' column and refresh the last_cell afterwards
            If False Then
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete
                .Parent.UsedRange
            End If
        End With
    End With
```

Keep the formula as simple as possible. Remember to remove the 'helper' column and refresh the [xlCellTypeLastCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) after you have finished working with the filtered results.

---

**Option 3: [.AutoFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) on [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule**

The same logic as the 'helper' column solution can be applied through a [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule and .AutoFilter can filter on a color applied to matching rows.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Conditional_Formatting]
           <sup>Sample data showing [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule</sup>

As code:

```
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
                                      Formula1:="=OR($L2=""ABC"",$AA2<>""DEF"")"
                .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
                .FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = vbRed
            End With
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                        Criteria1:=vbRed, Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                .FormatConditions(1).Delete
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

The obvious benefit here is that there is no column of formulas to 'clean up'.

---

**Option 4: using a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) object on a column with unique values**

If you have a column that contains unique values, loop through the rows comparing your criteria to the values in column L and AA. If they match, record the value from the unique column in a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx)'s [keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc.aspx) and use the keys as an array of criteria.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Scripting_Dictionary]
           <sup>Sample data showing [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) rule</sup>

As code:

```
    Dim d As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For d = 2 To .Rows.Count
                If LCase(.Cells(d, "L")) = "abc" Or LCase(.Cells(d, "AA")) <> "def" Then _
                    dict.Add Key:=CStr(.Cells(d, "A").Text), Item:=vbNullString
            Next d
            With .Columns(1)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dict.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        End With
    End With

    dict.RemoveAll: Set dict = Nothing
```

This may seem like a lot of work compared to the other methods but it is ultimately faster for large blocks of data with complicated criteria¹.

---

**Option 5: pseudo-AutoFilter with the [Range.Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx) property on the [Range.EntireRow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx)**

This may be the simplest solution. Simply loop through the rows comparing the criteria against column L and AA. Gather the rows that **do not** match with the [Union method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) and apply the [Range.Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx) property on the collection of [Range.EntireRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx) properties.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Pseudo_Filter]
           <sup>Sample data rows to receive the [Range.Hidden](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx) property adjustment</sup>

As code:

```
    Dim d As Long, rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .EntireRow.Hidden = False
            For d = 2 To .Rows.Count
                If (LCase(.Cells(d, "L").Value2) <> "abc" And _
                    LCase(.Cells(d, "AA").Value2) = "def") Then
                    If rng Is Nothing Then
                        Set rng = .Rows(d)
                    Else
                        Set rng = Union(rng, .Rows(d))
                    End If
                End If
            Next d
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
    End With
```

Remember that you have to **reverse** the criteria since you plan to hide the rows that **do not** match. The implied caveat here is that you need to select the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) and unhide the rows to remove the imitation filter.

---

**[Results:](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/How%20do%20I%20autofilter%20and%20display%20rows%20based%20on%20criterions%20from%202%20columns.xlsb)**

Any of the five methods detailed above should produce results similar to the following.

[image: autofilter_or_fields_Results]
           <sup>Results after applying any of the filtering methods</sup>

---

¹ <sub>See **[Can AutoFilter take both inclusive and non-inclusive wildcards from Dictionary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614417)** for examples of complex multiple criteria using a [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) as arrayed criteria for the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx)</sub>