# Simulate AdvancedFilter CriteriaRange Object through array

Tags: excel, vba, filter, advanced-filter

***Background***

This could end up being a rather silly question, however I wish to still ask it to be sure. As of recently I been introduced to [`AdvancedFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter) through VBA, and reading the `CriteriaRange` parameter takes a `Variant` data type I thought it may have been able to take an array instead of an actual `Range` as the name suggests.

***Sample Data***

For this I have set up a simple data set:

```
| Hdr1 | Hdr2 | Hdr3 |
|------|------|------|
| A    | X    | 1    |
| B    | Y    | 2    |
| A    | Z    | 3    |
| A    | Y    | 4    |
| B    | Y    | 5    |
| A    | Z    | 6    |
```

This data sits on sheet with `CodeName` "Source". Besides that, I added a sheet called "Destination" as to where I want the filtered criteria to be pasted through `xlFilterCopy`.

***Code***

A simple working code would be:

```
Sub FilterTest()

Dim rng as range
Dim arr(1 To 2, 1 To 3) As Variant

arr(1, 1) = "Hdr1"
arr(1, 2) = "Hdr2"
arr(1, 3) = "Hdr3"
arr(2, 1) = "A"
'arr(2, 2) = "" 'Leaving empty for now
'arr(2, 3) = "" 'Leaving empty for now

Set rng = Destination.Range("A1:C2")
rng = arr

Source.Range("A1:C7").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rng, CopyToRange:=Destination.Range("A4")

End Sub
```

**Problem/Curiosity**

As the above works fine, I'm curious if there is a way to avoid filling the `CriteriaRange` prior to applying the `AdvancedFilter`, or even implement the `arr` array directly. As is, I believe we can't but I am curious to be proven wrong.

Whereas filling the evenly dimensioned `rng` with `arr` works, obviously the following line will error (1004) out:

```
Source.Range("A1:D7").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=arr, CopyToRange:=Destination.Range("A4")
```

The [`Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type) data type for `CriteriaRange` seems to be expected (as per the documentation) but seemingly only the `Range` objects are actual working parameters.

Any definate answer as to whether it's possible? =)

Comment: The MS documentation is not helpful! Shows how to use the command in its blandest form, but doesn't provide any clues on why it works or the impact of some variations in usage have. But my main question is "Why?". Apart from curiosity or the love of a good coding challenge, of course. If you are using an array to determine the `Criteria`, then your code is probably faster if you worked through an array of source values as well - negating the need for expensive range conversions and application function calls. I know this comment is challenging the framing of the question - all in good fun.

Comment: @AJD, thanks for the response. As to the 'why?', mainly to see if there is a way to use the parameter without a physical representation of the CriteriaRange anywhere in the project. And yes, that's merely a question comming from curiosity =)

Comment: Same question, more or less, was asked on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532282/can-advanced-filter-criteria-be-in-the-vba-rather-than-a-range and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614417/can-autofilter-take-both-inclusive-and-non-inclusive-wildcards-from-dictionary-k and it seems that nobody found the way.

Comment: It's called CriteriaRange so a range only I would say, Variant because an empty range, String or Variant will also work on Advanced Filter.

Comment: I don't think CriteriaRange can be filled directly without range filter.

Comment: For your need, I think you can use normal filter. You can put your criteria directly or store in an array, then you can copy the result to your destination. If you want, I will make a sample with your simple data and your criteria.

Comment: @user11982798, thanks but no, working with `AdvancedFilter` per se is not the problem, hence why I provided a working example in my question. The problem/question I got is wheather we can manipulate the parameter to take a variant variable being something different than a range. To prevent physical representation of `CriteriaRange` within the project.