# Auto Filter sort in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm making a VBA macro. At one point, the macro tells excel to change the current autofilter to have the autofilter's sort be on the column in `Column A`, and it should be ascending.

But, the VBA code that I have now states that the RANGE is hard-coded which is `Range(A1:A655)`,that's because the code was written in a recorded Macro. Below is my VBA code. Can you tell me how to change the `A1:A655` not in a hard-coded way, instead make it just generically mean "make the range be ALL of the rows in that column, however much there is?

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("A1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(
        "A1:A655"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have written more clearly... I should have said that the code now states the KEY range to be hard coded A1:A655.   The KEY argument is the one that I am concerned with.

Comment: And I am so sorry to add more here...  I also need basically the same question answered  about this other VBA command, which is a FILTER not a sort.   This command I also need to have the "hard-coded range" removed from is the following... any tips on this one also?   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$EK$655").AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:="1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid relying on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx). You should know what worksheet you are on and explicitly reference it by the Worksheet [.CodeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837552.aspx) or 
Worksheet [.Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) property.

I believe you've mixed up a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) with a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx). That is, unless you actually have a worksheet named **A1** which does not seem likely.

The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) is an excellent method of referencing the uninterrupted block of cells radiating out from A1. It continues down and right  until it meets a fully blank row and fully blank column. Single or small groups of intermediate blank cells do not interrupt its reference to the block of cells.

```
    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 141)  '<~~ A:EK
                    .AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=1

                    'the CurrentRegion is sorted on column A and filtered
                    'on column AJ

                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
```

The nested [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)s progessively defines the block of cells you wish to reference.

I believe you are better off with a conventional [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx). It is more straightforward than a .AutoFilter.Sort. A subsequent [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx) finishes off the operation.

Comment: also just as an aside... in fact my workbook does have a worksheet named A1!  also A2, A3, and B1, B2, C1, D1 ... owing to the nature of my work.  Funny coincidence that will probably confuse things more than once! :)

Comment: Yes, it seemed like you were supplying working code but I could not reconcile the **A1** reference; no worries as long as you are keeping them straight. In future questions it may be an idea to specifically mention that or you might get questionable interpretations like my own.

Comment: Again, this is so helpful to me. Before I proceed, I had just a couple questions about the code you supplied above. I am wondering about the nested "With .Resize" command that you placed into the code. 
(1) Could that be seen as unnecessary if I was confident that the "Currentregion" code above it had already identified the correct full block of cells for the operations? In other words, A:EK was already specified perfectly in that earlier step?
(2) If I could indeed be sure that the Currentregion had correctly grabbed the right region, what would I do to the code to remove that "With .Resize"?

Comment: Just remove that line and its accompanying End With. If you data allows for A:EK when using CurrentRegion then there is no need for it. It is only there because I couldn't be sure.

Comment: Thanks, you're great. One more question popped to mind that exposes my novice aspect even more. For the filter, I do understand that if I want to make the filter involve two conditions at the same time, like x AND y, then I simply add an additional .AutoFilter Field....... line and rows will have to match both criteria. But... what if I want to have the filter be two conditions "or'ed" together... like rows should appear if x condition OR y condition?  What is the most graceful way to make your above code do that?  Thanks again for this help -- Eric

Comment: That would be a different question. You might have a look at [Can Advanced Filter criteria be in the VBA rather than a range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532282/can-advanced-filter-criteria-be-in-the-vba-rather-than-a-range)