# Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set - Why I can't sort the rows in the sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

In a part of my code, I'm trying to sort the rows but I don't now why is VBA showing me this error.

I have tried to Set the variable DBws again before the With, and I have tried not to use the With, but it's the same. 
In others codes I had already used this piece of code in the same way and I didn't have any problem.

```
Dim DBws as Worksheet
Set DBws = Target.Sheets("Raw Data")
Set HeaderCell = DataRng.Find("Received", LookAt:=xlPart)
If HeaderCell Is Nothing Then Set HeaderCell = DataRng.Find("Received", LookAt:=xlWhole)
LastR = lastRow(Tws, 1)
Set DataRng = DBws.Range(Cells(HeaderCell.Row, HeaderCell.Column), Cells(LastR, HeaderCell.Column))        

With DBws
    .Columns.AutoFit
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear '<--- Debugging highlights this line
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    DataRng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
    :=xlSortNormal

    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofilter): "The property returns Nothing if filtering is off."

Comment: @Comintern, my bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't tell us on which line of your code the error occurs. I suspect it should be on `Set DataRng = DBws.Range(Cells(HeaderCell.Row, HeaderCell.Column)...`. If so, the error originates from this little piece of illogic:-

```
Set HeaderCell = DataRng.Find("Received", LookAt:=xlPart)
If HeaderCell Is Nothing Then Set HeaderCell = DataRng.Find("Received", LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Presuming that *DataRng* is set to something earlier in your code you look for the word "Received" as a part of any cell's content. If it isn't found you look for a cell that contains nothing but "Received". If such a cell existed it would have been found with the partial search. Therefore, if it wasn't found in the first search it won't be found in the second either. If the first search is unsuccessful the second one occurs. If the second one doesn't turn up a result your code crashes the moment you try to use the *HeaderCell* range.

I suggest that you look up the `Find` function. Many of its properties are remembered from the previous use. Therefore, if you use the `Find` function manually and then run your code where most of the properties are not set (and therefore retrieved from memory) you must expect the unexpected.

Comment: `.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear '<--- Debugging highlights this line`

Comment: Sorry. You did say and I overlooked. `Sort` is a method of the `Range` object. Somehow Excel seems to see the `Range.Autofilter` object also as a range but not always. My guess is that the SortFields your code tries to delete don't exist, either because your code deleted them on a previous test run or because they belong to the `Range` (not the `Range.AutoFilter`) object. You might test for their existence before the *Delete* command or try `On Error Resume Next` before that line and see what happens.

Comment: In this thread the selected author argues that the AutoFilter could be applied after the sort and such avoid the contentious `Range.AutoFilter.Sort` entirely.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695901/auto-filter-sort-in-vba.

Comment: Variatus, I'm not the op. I just dropped off that codeline as you seemed to have overlooked it.

Comment: Your answer make me review what I was doing and give me one idea that worked! I just had to  make sure that the `Sheet.AutoFilter` property was enabled and then the code ran successfully.  Thanks a lot to all you.