# VBA: Filtering and Sorting a pre-existing Autofilter range

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have an Excel worksheet which contains information about my music collection. I've written 2 macros: the first sorts the list by artist, album, and track number, and the second sorts the list by genre and song title. Here's what the macros look like:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").ShowAllData
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").AutoFilter.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Range("A:A"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Range("B:B"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Range("C:C"), xlSortOnValues, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I want to add a line which filters a specific genre, like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock"
```

This line doesn't work because the Worksheet.AutoFilter method doesn't accept the same arguments as the Range.Autofilter method. Does anyone know a way around this that doesn't involve turning the filter off, figuring out the data range, applying a new filter, and then sorting that?

Comment: Why aren't you using the Range.Autofilter method?

Comment: @SJR Using the Range.Autofilter method would require devoting code to figuring out what the range is every time. It seems redundant since the filter already exists. Excel must have it's range stored in memory somewhere. I'm trying to manipulate the existing filter rather than create a new one in the same place every time.

Comment: Another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695901/auto-filter-sort-in-vba

Comment: Yes, I know how to turn off the current filter and apply a new one. I don't want to do that unless absolutely necessary. I'm trying to find a more elegant, less redundant solution.

Comment: Turn your range into a List. Much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may use any cellrange, even one without the range of the already defined autofilter.**

```
Option Explicit

Sub add_filter_2_existing_autofilter()
Dim FilterRange As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").Select

    'ShowAllData - error if no filter is set
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    'These do not work
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock"
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Set FilterRange = Sheets("Music").AutoFilter.Range
    FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    'OR one of the following equivalents, which also work:
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").Range(FilterRange.Address).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").Range("A1000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Music").Range("XFD1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="Rock", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!