# Custom filter for range of years to target year of birth

Tags: excel, excel-2007

In Excel 2007 I have a column with thousands of numbers, where the first part of the number is the date of birth; `mmddYYxxxxx`. I'm looking for a way to use a custom filter to get only those with date of birth (YY) between 00 and 15.

Example:

```
1103**81**12345
0112**04**12345
```

I would like the filter to hide the first entry, but not the last one. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards)

Comment: Well, I'm not primarily looking to solve this using VBA, but via Number Filters > Custom Filters . If that's even possible.

Comment: As mentioned in that linked answer, there are a maximum of two wildcards and neither accept **>**, **<** or substrings. You have to build an array of matches from the criteria field and use that as Criteria1. Or you can just do it manually by checking/unchecking the matching records. You may want to consider a 'helper' column that pulls the year out of the mashup of numbers and filter on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper cell to determine whether the data falls into your desired date range.  Then you will be able to filter on the helper cell.

Assuming your data starts in `A2`, the following formula will determine if you want to "skip" or "keep" the data.

```
=IF(OR(VALUE(MID(A2,4,2))>15,VALUE(MID(A2,4,2))<0),"Skip","Keep")
```

[image: helpercell]

You can then `filter` out the "Skips" so that only your desired data remains:

[image: helpercell2]