# Excel "Begins With..." range of alphabet letters

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter a column to show all rows that start with the letters A through I. I have looked at the VBA code and I see that for two criteria it shows:

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "=a*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=b*"`

How would I tell it to only show letters A THROUGH I?

*I would also not like to use Advanced Filter if at all possible.

Comment: You'll have to use a workaround.  See [here for using a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards/34822944#34822944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using an advanced filter, this should work

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
    ">=a", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<j"
```

Comment: WOW! You are THE man Tom. Thank you! Just beautiful how some people know these things, bravo sir!