# AutoFilteR with an array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter my table by looking if a cell contains one of those names, and when I use theFor it shows all data in one row.

Here is the code:

```
    Dim tab(3) as string '
    'tab(0) = "*valerie dupond*"'
'tab(1) = "*emanuel babri*"'
'tab(2) = "*raphael gerand*"'

For i = 0 To 2

'Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=tab , ''Operator:=xlFilterValues'

'Next'
```

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193554/pies-den @Aya Lahrichi

Comment: Can you provide your excel sheet and expected output sheet. No guarantee  but i will try to help @Aya Lahrichi

Comment: Mutliple wildcards are not allowed in `.AutoFilter` (maximum is 2). Therefore you need to workaround as described in the answer that I linked in the top of your question.

Comment: Hi I think you need to create an array in the criteria itself.    **wb.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=bdlgschc, Criteria1:=Array("RMS", "ATC", "RMS IND", "FIRE"), Operator:=xlFilterValues**  This line works for me .... If you can try and create a criteria like this it should work.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code line that works for me.

Comment: @MohitBansal note that she tried to use wildcards `*` and you did not. There are only a maximum of 2 wildcards allowed in `.Autofilter` but she tried using 3. Therefore your approach will not work for her.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ .... Okay. Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is that you can't have wildcards ("/*") when you filter on an array.

​

Getting around that restriction is difficult, but not impossible. The way I've done it before is to do something like this:

1) Copy all of the values in the column you are filtering on (column 2, I think) to a blank sheet.

2) Remove duplicates.

3) Loop through all of the remaining rows and delete any that do not match the criteria.

4) Put the remaining values in an array.

5) Filter the original data on that array.

I don't have access to the code, but it is something like what is below. I didn't test it. I'm not on a computer with Excel right now so you will have to clean it up, fix the errors and also enable Regular Expressions in Visual Basic. Should be in the Tools->References menu. You can also tinker with this code a bit to manipulate it to do it.

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim c As Integer

Dim lRow As Integer

Dim regEx As New RegExp

Dim rEx As String

Dim arr(1) As String



lRow = Range(shSheet.Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlup).Row 'Get's the last row of the current column selected so make sure to select the column you are trying to filter.



rEx = "^.*(valerie dupond|emanuel babri|raphael gerand).*$" ' The test string for the Regular Expression to match


'Setting up the Regular Expression.

With regEx

.Global = True

.MultiLine = True

.IgnoreCase = False

.Pattern = strPattern

End With



i = 0 'Sets i to be looped through your values.

c = 1 'C will be set to store the values in the array.



'Loops through every row in your table trying to match the pattern above

For i to lRow

If regEx.Test(LCase(ActiveCell.Value)) Then
arr(c) = ActiveCell.Value

c = c + 1

ReDim Preserve arr(c)

End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
Next i



'Sets the filter

Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=arr , ''Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

**Method 2:**

Two points:

1. You don't need the FOR loop. Criteria1=tab will filter for all the criteria, no loop needed
2. You cannot use wildcards if you are using this array method to search for multiple terms. If you want to use wildcards, you have to use different syntax and are limited to just two terms

**code 2**

Just remove the wildcards. For example if you need to just match "valerie dupond" but not "Mrs. valerie dupond"

```
Sub FilterMe()
        Dim names(3) As String
        names(0) = "valerie dupond"
        names(1) = "emanuel babri"
        names(2) = "raphael gerand"
        Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=names, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End Sub
```

Again you cannot use autofilter to filter more than two terms with wildcards

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for your help , do you still have the code ?

Comment: I am busy right now. But i will try to help you. You can contact me at whatisimp4u@gmail.com @Aya Lahrichi

Comment: @AyaLahrichi I added code.

Comment: Thank you So much Pie . but Still got the same problem

Comment: Did method two helped? @AyaLahrichi

Comment: hello @pie no it's not working too

Comment: Check filter me method @AyaLahrichi

Comment: Hello Pie but i need to find the name ex : Valerie Dupond in a text for exemple mrs valerie dupond test test test sothe macro should filter all the names who exist in this text

Comment: Check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards @AyaLahrichi