# VBA Excel - If Found in List, Then Omit

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script that compares values in one list to values in another.  If the value is not found in the comparison list, I would like to copy the whole row from one worksheet to another.

Using Application.VLookup/Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup, I'm getting a debug error 13/1004 because no value is found.  I'd like to trigger off of that no value found to make the copy.

```
Function Update()

Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Slave As Worksheet
Dim lrM As Long
Dim lrS As Long
Dim i As Long, m, MLookup As Range
'Dim j As Long, n, SLookup As Range

Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data")

Set MLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data").Columns(1)
'Set SLookup = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill").Columns(7)

lrM = Master.Cells(Master.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lrS = Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Master
    For i = 2 To lrM
        m = Application.Match(.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, MLookup, 0)
        If IsError(m) Then
            .Rows(i).Copy Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next i
End With

'With Slave
'    For j = 2 To lrS
'        n = Application.Match(.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value, SLookup, 0)
'        If IsError(n) Then
'            .Rows(j).Copy Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'        End If
'    Next j
'End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox ("Matrix Update Complete")

End Function
```

Comment: Try setting a variable of type `Range` equal to `Range.Find` then test `If RangeVariable Is Nothing Then`....

Comment: If you are looking to keep to your current use of a vlookup, you can wrap it in `If IsError() Then` and do the copy.  The end result is similar to @Brian 's, where a check is performed.  `IsError` will return boolean (true/false)

Comment: First, [avoid using `.SELECT` and `.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) it's rarely necessary and this isn't one of those cases. Second, I'm confused - I don't see any reference to `.Vlookup` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my best guess (including second lookup):

```
Sub Update()

    Dim Master As Worksheet
    Dim Slave As Worksheet
    Dim lrM As Long
    Dim lrS As Long
    Dim i As Long, m, MLookup As Range, SLookup As Range

    Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data Windchill")
    Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PR Data")

    Set MLookup = Slave.Columns(1)  '<< reference list
    Set SLookup = Master.Columns(1) '<< reference list

    lrM = Master.Cells(Master.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lrS = Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With Master
        For i = 2 To lrM
            'drop the worksheetfunction to avoid a run-time error,
            '   and instead check the return value for an error
            m = Application.Match(.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, MLookup, 0)
            If IsError(m) Then
                'no match, so copy over
                .Rows(i).Copy Slave.Cells(Slave.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    With Slave
        For i = 2 To lrS
            m = Application.Match(.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, SLookup, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                Master.Cells(m, 7).Copy S.Rows(i).Cells(1)
            End If
        Next j
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    MsgBox "Matrix Update Complete"

End Function
```

Comment: This worked!  I need help expanding the function, though.  I've updated the original code to reflect what's changed.  Using the "PR Data Windchill" tab data, I need to update a field 7th to the right in "PR Data".  What have I shifted wrong?

Comment: Would help to explain what's changed.  Also  - it's best not to alter your question's original code, otherwise your whole question starts to make no sense to anyone who comes along later.

Comment: I added a new With Slave section that wasn't there previously.  The intent is to review and update a cell instead of copying a whole row.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to copy from where to where?

Comment: On Slave, Copy from PR Data Windchill, 7th column per matched row and paste it onto the matching row 7th column of PR Data per matched row.

Comment: Can you help me with this question? I tried everything I knew but could not solve. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207459/8631622 @Tim Williams