# Data validation to a dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column named "time" in my excel sheet. I want to write a code such that whenever user performs an entry in time column, if it is a whole number, it should accept, but if it is not a pop up should appear saying "only numbers allowed". Also, the validation should be dynamic i.e. should automatically validate next row if users enters a new entry

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = Range("Meeting Time").Column Then

    If Not (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then

        MsgBox "only numbers allowed"

        Target.Value = ""

        Target.Select
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your actual code instead of screenshots of it. Is there a specific reason why this needs to be done via VBA? It seems to me that it can be easily done with the data validation tool in excel. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Posted actual code. I want the validation to be dynamic. There are two columns, lets say one is User Name and the other one is Time. At present there are 4 entries in user name and time each. If a new entry is made now, I want the validation on time column to be active for the new entry. If it can be achieved through excel itself then please guide me on that

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be dynamic? It seems to me that if you just apply a data validation rule to the whole column, you would be covered. No?

Comment: Yeah. I can apply validation to the whole column

Comment: Again, maybe I'm missing something, but I think you could just select the column you want, go to `Data>Data Validation` on excel's ribbon and just add a data validation rule for the whole column by specifying the `Allow` as `Whole Number`, the `Minimum` as `1` and the `Maximum` as `160`? You can also customize the `Error Alert` message to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '1. Check if the column that affected is B (change to the column you want)
    '2. Check if changed field is one (used to avoid errors if user change more than one cells at the same time)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        'Check if target is numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Call Clear(Target)
        End If
        'Check if target.offset(1,0) is numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
            Call Clear(Target.Offset(1, 0))
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub Clear(ByVal rng As Range)

    'Disable events in order to prevent code to re trigger when clear cell
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng.Value = ""
    'Enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**EDITED VERSION:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    '1. Check if the column that affected is B (change to the column you want)
    '2. Check if changed field is one (used to avoid errors if user change more than one cells at the same time)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        'Check if target is numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Call Clear(Target)
        ElseIf Target.Value > 160 Or (Target.Value = Int(Target.Value) = False) Then
             Call Clear(Target)
        End If
        'Check if target.offset(1,0) is numeric
        If Not IsNumeric(Target.Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
            Call Clear(Target.Offset(1, 0))
        ElseIf Target.Offset(1, 0).Value > 160 Or (Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = Int(Target.Offset(1, 0).Value) = False) Then
            Call Clear(Target)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Sub Clear(ByVal rng As Range)

    'Disable events in order to prevent code to re trigger when clear cell
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    rng.Value = ""
    'Enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What do I need to change if I need to prevent decimal numbers as well. Only integers less than 160 are allowed

Comment: Not working. Even integers less than 160 are getting cleared

Comment: No, I have copy pasted the same code. On entering values such as 123, 110,25 etc, the entry is being cleared

Comment: debug the code and tell me at which point the code clear your cell. At `If Not IsNumeric` or `ElseIf Target.Offset`

Answer (score 0):

first you can create a range name for column you want your "time" and you can use the sample codes below.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = Range("time").Column Then

      If Not (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then

        MsgBox "only numbers allowed"

        Target.Value = ""

        Target.Select

      End If

    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: How do i create a range name. I want it to be dynamic i.e. I want it to take the range from row 2 to last row. Please bear with me, I'm new to VBA

Comment: yes it will be dynamic, as you may notice on the code, we are only checking the column. if you want you can specify the column number. you may use this instead If Target.Column = 1 Then, meaning its checking on column A

Comment: I'm unable to run this code. I am not getting an option to run this sub. I'm being shown all other subs except this one

Comment: is your excel macro enabled?, did you add the code under workbook?

Comment: Yes. I have created 4 subs all of which I'm able to execute. But not this one. I have got 4 sheets on my workbook with time column present in the "input" sheet

Comment: see the sample image i have attached above

Comment: I too have attached two images to my original question. Please see them and tell what is wrong

Comment: Can you help me with this question? I tried everything I knew but could not solve. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56207459/8631622 @jonrizz

Comment: @RithwikSarma, did try your code and its look working fine with me? is there any error you encountered?